# How to stop thumbnail from blowing up into the background?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

On this theme: http://www.fabthemes.com/tiberion/,
when you go to a single post, the thumbnail is blown up into the background automatically.

How can I stop this from happening? I just want 1 single background for all posts and the main page.

I've tried looking through the style.css for anything related to the background, but no luck. I've also tried scouring through the single.php and index.php. Am I missing something?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: were is single post option..?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but let me clarify.
By "single post", I mean when you click one of the posts to read the content, the background changes into a blown up version of the featured image.